# Why can't I save as PDF in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, mac

Running Google Chrome 105.0.5195/102 (Official Build)(arm64) on MacBook Pro running version 12.5.1

From any web page or Google Doc:

- File > Print
- Set Destination to Save as PDF
- Click Save

The finder window appears briefly against a slightly grayed background and then it disappears, preventing the option to select destination and Save the PDF.

I have rebooted the computer. I Reset Chrome in Settings > Reset settings and the problem persists. I do not have any problems saving to PDF using Safari or any other Mac apps.

I am able to use File > Open File to view existing PDF documents in Chrome

I expected to be able to save a file to PDF.

Comment: Also see: [macOS Chrome unable to save PDF via print dialog](https://superuser.com/a/1810636/860750)

Answer (score 10):

I was viewing this on another person's computer and discovered that they had Chrome in full-screen mode. As soon they took it out of full-screen mode Save as PDF worked correctly.

This appears to be a rather obscure bug in Chrome.