# macOS Chrome unable to save PDF via print dialog

Tags: macos, google-chrome, pdf, printing

Since last few months my Chrome has been glitching when trying to save PDF via print dialog.

- Upon hitting that blue `Save` button on the print dialog I don't see any file explorer to select location for saving file, nor does any file get saved anywhere on it's own
- Rather a greyed out overlay covering entire screen is displayed and when I hit `Esc` I return back to same print dialog

[image: Print dialog grayed out overlay]

I've tried all the basics like

- updating macOS to latest release
- updating Chrome to latest build
- rebooting PC (!)

---

Any suggested fixes or workarounds?

I'm currently on

- 16 inch macBook Pro (2021) with Apple M1 Pro
- macOS Ventura 13.5.2 (22G91)
- Chrome Version 117.0.5938.132 (Official Build) (arm64)

Answer (score 4):

Not a fix, but I found a simple workaround.

1. On that Chrome print dialog, expand **`More settings`** section and click on **`Open PDF in Preview`** option at the bottom (just above that blue `Save` button)
2. Once file opens in `Preview`, hit **`File` > `Save`** to save it as PDF

[image: Expand More settings and Open PDF in Preview]

[image: Save PDF file via Preview]

---

#### UPDATE

As suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/1741568/860750) a simple(r) workaround is **resizing Chrome from full-screen mode to windowed mode**, after which that gray overlay problem goes away

[image: Resizing from full-screen mode to windowed mode fixes the problem]